# Pandas merge with logic

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to merge two dataframes, but can't exactly figure out how to do so without iterating. Basically, I want to merge a row from df2 to df1 if df1.date >= df2.start_date and df1.date <= df2.end_date. See example below:

```
df1:
index   date         value
0       2012-08-01   82
1       2012-08-02   20
2       2012-08-03   94
...
n-1     2012-10-29   58
n       2012-10-30   73

df2:
index   start_date   end_date     other_value
0       2012-08-01   2012-09-04   'foo'
1       2012-09-05   2012-10-15   'bar'
2       2012-10-16   2012-11-01   'foobar'
...


final_df:
index   df2_index   date         value  other_value
0       0           2012-08-01   82     'foo'
1       0           2012-08-02   20     'foo'
2       0           2012-08-03   94     'foo'
...
n-1     2           2012-10-29   58     'foobar'
n       2           2012-10-30   73     'foobar'
```

I thought about creating a date series vector to merge with df2, so that I can combine on date, but it seems very manual and does not leverage the power/speed of pandas. I also thought about trying to expand df2 into single days, but couldn't find any way to do so without a manual / iteration type solution.

Comment: Are the intervals defined by `start_date` and `end_date` disjoint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The naive iterative approach is `O(n*m)`, where `n = len(df1)` and `m = len(df2)`, since for each date in `df1` you would have to check its inclusion in up to `m` intervals.

If the intervals defined by `df2` are disjoint, then there is a theoretically better way: use [searchsorted](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Index.searchsorted.html) to find where each date in `df1` fits amongst the start_dates, and then use `searchsorted` a second time to find where each date fits amongst the end_dates. When the index from the two calls to `searchsorted` are equal, the date falls inside an interval.

Searchsorted assumes the cutoff dates are sorted and it uses binary search, so each call has complexity O(n*log(m)).

If `m` is large enough, using `searchsorted` should be faster 
than the naive iterative approach.

If `m` is not large, the iterative approach may be faster.

---

Here is an example, using `searchsorted`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Timestamp = pd.Timestamp
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': (Timestamp('2012-08-01'),
                             Timestamp('2012-08-02'),
                             Timestamp('2012-08-03'),
                             Timestamp('2012-10-29'),
                             Timestamp('2012-10-30'),
                             Timestamp('2012-11-01'),
                             Timestamp('2012-10-15'),  # on then end_date
                             Timestamp('2012-09-04'),  # outside an interval
                             Timestamp('2012-09-05'),  # on then start_date
                             ),
                    'value': (82, 20, 94, 58, 73, 1, 2, 3, 4)})

print(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'end_date': (
                        Timestamp('2012-10-15'),
                        Timestamp('2012-09-04'),
                        Timestamp('2012-11-01')),
                    'other_value': ("foo", "bar", "foobar"),
                    'start_date': (
                        Timestamp('2012-09-05'),
                        Timestamp('2012-08-01'),
                        Timestamp('2012-10-16'))})
df2 = df2.reindex(columns=['start_date', 'end_date', 'other_value'])
df2.sort(['start_date'], inplace=True)
print(df2)

# Convert to DatetimeIndexes so we can call the searchsorted method
date_idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1['date'])
start_date_idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['start_date'])
# Add one to the end_date so the original end_date will be included in the
# half-open interval.
end_date_idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['end_date'])+pd.DateOffset(days=1)

start_idx = start_date_idx.searchsorted(date_idx, side='right')-1
end_idx = end_date_idx.searchsorted(date_idx, side='right')
df1['idx'] = np.where(start_idx == end_idx, end_idx, np.nan)

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['idx'], right_index=True)
result = result.reindex(columns=['idx', 'date', 'value', 'other_value'])
print(result)
```

---

With `df1` equal to

```
        date  value
0 2012-08-01     82
1 2012-08-02     20
2 2012-08-03     94
3 2012-10-29     58
4 2012-10-30     73
5 2012-11-01      1
6 2012-10-15      2
7 2012-09-04      3
8 2012-09-05      4
```

and `df2` equal to

```
  start_date   end_date other_value
1 2012-08-01 2012-09-04         bar
0 2012-09-05 2012-10-15         foo
2 2012-10-16 2012-11-01      foobar
```

the above code yields

```
   idx       date  value other_value
0    0 2012-08-01     82         foo
1    0 2012-08-02     20         foo
2    0 2012-08-03     94         foo
7    0 2012-09-04      3         foo
3    2 2012-10-29     58      foobar
4    2 2012-10-30     73      foobar
5    2 2012-11-01      1      foobar
6    1 2012-10-15      2         bar
8    1 2012-09-05      4         bar
```

Comment: Wow this is fast. I thought my naive implementation was relatively fast, I sorted both dataframes and held the index of df1 and df2 so that I was at O(m+n). I was getting ~1.5 seconds for len(df1)=720 and len(df2)=25, your implementation is clocking in at .002 seconds. Maybe the inclusion step was the bottleneck? Either way, thank you so much. Is there a good place to find optimizations like this one or do you just know this from experience?

Comment: Much of what I know comes from seeing others do similar things. I don't have a citation for this particular trick, but once you are aware of the existence of `searchsorted`, the application follows pretty naturally.